# How to hide a wrapper then shows up automatically

Tags: jquery

I need some help on how to hide an element automatically then it will shows up within a seconds automatically in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
$('#toHide').delay(2000).hide(0);​ // delay 2 seconds then hide.
```

*[**The live demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLxMn/)*

Answer (score 0):

use delay its simple and will get it done

you can use like this

```
$('#foo').hide(300).delay(800).show(400);
```

and check this
http://api.jquery.com/delay/